# How to Implement New hook script for checkout

Tags: svn

I am using SVN on windows. By default, there are 9 hooks are available in `hooks` folder in Repository path like `pre-commit`, `post-commit`, `pre-lock`...

Is there is a way to implement new hook script like `pre-checkout` and `post-checkout`?

I want to check whether the user has the permission to checkout the corresponding files and I need to send notification, if any user checkout any file or folders in the repository.

So I need pre-checkout & post-checkout hooks.

Comment: Path-based authorization of Apache Subversion will help you with this "I want to check whether the user has the permission to checkout the corresponding files".

Answer (score 1):

The hooks you see are simply placeholders for the hooks that are recognized. Whether or not someone can checkout the code is part of the server configuration.

You don't say how your Subversion server is configured, but there are three general ways `svnserve over ssh`, `svnserver`, and `Apache http(s)`. Each one has its own security mechanism,  My preference is to use Apache over LDAP/ActiveDirectory. This allows users to use their Windows credentials to login, and I can use Windows groups for checkout security. I even have a hook script that handles commits that can use Windows groups to see whether or not a user is allowed to change a file.

I never heard of a requirement to request email to be sent out on a checkout. (I have a post-commit script that can send emails on a commit). However, I suppose it's possible to watch the Apache log file and send an email out based upon that. Usually, you don't care about checkouts. You care about commits which is why most software will allow *watchers* on commits, but not on checkouts.

---

Sorry for the disappointing answer. Basically, it's *"No, you can't do that."*

Answer (score 0):

As far as "checking for permission" goes, what you're looking for is called Path-Based Authorization.  There is [a good explanation of how to implement it in the Subversion manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html).  You don't need hook functions, Subversion's configuration allows this to be done directly.

As far as the "checkout notification" goes, can you be more specific about what you are looking for?  Are you wanting something like an email alert every time that someone runs a `svn checkout` command?  What, ultimately, are are you trying to accomplish with this?  It sounds like there might be a better way to approach the problem.